# Should the tags [sortable], [jquery-sortable] and [jquery-ui-sortable] be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

Should the tags [sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sortable), [jquery-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-sortable) and [jquery-ui-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-sortable) be merged?

Here are the descriptions for each:

[sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sortable) 10 asked this week, 24 this month, 1329 total

> A jQuery UI framework plugin which allows a developer to create a group of sortable blocks, which can be dragged and reordered by mouse.

[jquery-ui-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-sortable) 12 asked this month, 262 this year, 1088 total

> The jQuery UI Sortable plugin makes selected elements sortable by dragging with the mouse.

[jquery-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-sortable) 51 asked this year, 238 total

> The jQuery UI Sortable plugin that can be used to reorder elements in a list or grid using the mouse.

I would argue that they are all referring to exactly the same thing.

Comment: Looks like [about 10%](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sortable+-jquery+-jquery-ui+-javascript) of the questions tagged [tag:sortable] aren't about the jQuery plugin and need retagging before merging the tags. Having about 90% relevance means that it's reasonable to merge [tag:sortable] into [tag:jquery-ui-sortable].

Comment: I think `jquery-sortable` should be used for this https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable some of the questions are referring to it.

Comment: @TJ That seems reasonable and the tag descriptions need to be reworded to make it clear they are different from each other.

Comment: @CJDennis Yea I can update the wiki. I have posted an answer and let's wait a while to see if someone has any objection before doing so.

Comment: Follow up question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327296/2333214

Answer (score 10):

These tags are a mess now. The most specific and clear tag out of the 3 is [jquery-ui-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-sortable) and is consistent with the tags for other jQuery UI widgets such as

- [jquery-ui-draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-draggable)
- [jquery-ui-droppable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-droppable)
- [jquery-ui-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-tabs)
- [jquery-ui-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-datepicker)
- [jquery-ui-slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-slider)

and so on.

---

The tag [sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sortable) is very ambiguous and is mostly used to refer to [jquery-ui-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-sortable). It's already suggested as a synonym of [jquery-ui-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-sortable) and I've voted on it.

---

The tag wiki of [jquery-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-sortable) currently points to jQuery UI sortable widget, but is being used in many questions referring to [jquery-sortable](https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable) plugin.

My recommendation is to update the wiki to mention clearly that it should be used to refer to [jquery-sortable](https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable) plugin and not [jquery-ui-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-sortable) widget.

But this will take some re-tagging and clean up first. I'd like to know the community opinion on this and if there is no objection I could use some help with the cleanup as well.

Comment: In my opinion, [tag:sortable] should not be merged with [tag:jquery-ui-sortable]. I wanted to retag [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599582/sortable-jumps-outside-container) as [tag:jquery] and [tag:sortable] separately, since relating it to jQuery UI Sortable is specifically inaccurate.

Comment: Is this still outstanding?

Comment: @TheCodesee I believe we cleaned up all these here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327296/2333214

Comment: @TJ May I ask the difference between merging the tags and creating a synonym? Would it not be more beneficial to merge the three tags?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was bought up on the 25th September 14, over two years ago and is still outstanding. I have decided to post my answer here after my [subsequent post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345098/merge-the-tags-sortable-jquery-ui-sortable-and-jquery-sortable) was closed as a duplicate.

I agree, as stated in the answer above by T J, the tag [jquery-ui-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-sortable) is the most accurate and therefore, [sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sortable) and [jquery-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-sortable) should be merged with it.