# Merge the tags [sortable], [jquery-ui-sortable] and [jquery-sortable]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

All three tags [sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sortable), [jquery-ui-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-sortable) and [jquery-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-sortable) are for the jQuery function `sortable` and therefore should be merged together.

[sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sortable) has this description:

> A jQuery UI framework plugin which allows a developer to create a group of sortable blocks, which can be dragged and reordered by

[jquery-ui-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-sortable) has this description:

> The jQuery UI Sortable plugin makes selected elements sortable by dragging with the mouse.

[jquery-sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-sortable) has this description:

> The jQuery UI Sortable plugin that can be used to reorder elements in a list or grid using the mouse.

While this could be seen as a duplicate of [Should the tags [sortable], [jquery-sortable] and [jquery-ui-sortable] be merged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272146/should-the-tags-sortable-jquery-sortable-and-jquery-ui-sortable-be-merged), I feel a need to bring this issue back up as there was no clear outcome in the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327229/5798798) as to whether or not the tags should be merged.